# Android : Different layout for different screens

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to develop an app for different devices. Where to create and save different layouts. Is there is any way to share the drawable-hdpi across all the layouts. I am more concerned if I need to save the same images in different set of drawable folders as this eat up lot of space.

Kindly advice.

Comment: you mean for various sizes your design will get change ?

Comment: layout textview font size changes.

Comment: there is no need to create new layouts for text alone

Comment: I tried dp / sp for text it is not filling the same % of screen in all devices. hence planning to create different layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tells you almost everything you need to know about these things: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

The key is that in addition to drawable-hdpi and friends, you can have hyphens for all your resources, like layout-hdpi.  But for layout you're probably most interested in the screen sizes, e.g. layout-large.

To answer your question about sharing, something in drawable-hdpi will be available to all screens, but will be shrunk down for mdpi and blown up for xhdpi.  The same thing in drawable will use the same number of raw pixels on any density screen, looking small on xhdpi and large on mdpi.

Comment: I created the layout in the folder raw/layout-large and raw/layout-small. when I tried the emulator for the screen 5.1"WVGA 480x800 , 2.7"QVGA (240x320) and 4.65" 720p (720*1280). It always  picks the layout from raw/layout-small

Comment: You don't put layouts in the raw folder.  The layout folders, layout-large, layout-normal, etc., would go in the same level as your layout folder, just like drawable-mdpi goes with drawable.  Try layout-normal, as the larger screens you tested on may actually be smaller than the large, depending on your pixel density.